# Notation for Expressing Sets of Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my book ( a generic introduction to higher math textbook ), we are given the following:

$B^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$ is the set of all n-sequences.

I'm taking this to mean $B$ is a set, an n-sequence is a sequence with $n$ elements, and $B^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$ is the set of all n-sequences composed of elements from $B$.

So, the superscript $^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$ is used to communicate three things: it is raised and therefore expresses some operation on $B$, this operation produces sequences ( but, for some reason, the superscript uses set brackets to suggest this fact ), and thirdly, everything between the opening and closing brackets, $^{1,2,...n}$, is merely there to indicate the length of the sets. ( But, if that is the case, wouldn't it be possible to express that idea by simply writing $^{n}$ rather than $^{1,2,...n}$ ? )

Clearly, I'm not understanding the intent of this notation.

Can anyone help explain it clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are any sets, $A^B$ denotes the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. Here, $B^{\{1,2,...,n\}}$ denotes the set of all functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $B$. This shouldn't be too weird; a sequence of length $n$ of elements from $B$ is essentially a way to assign an element of $B$ to each $k$ such that $1\leq k \leq n$.

This notation is used because, in the finite case, if $A$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements, then there are $n^m$ functions from $B$ to $A$. Since for each of the $m$ elements of $B$ we have $n$ choices of what to define as the image of that element, there are $n^m$ total ways to "build" a function from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: I like it; thank you!

I guess... I'm also taking a class on parsers in Computer Science right now and am thinking about how I would have a computer parse this notation. The amount of indirection in the notation is... I guess not too bad. $A$ and $\{1,2,...,n\}$ *are* equivalent.

The inner programmer in me thinks, "Right, the notation $A^B$ *does* imply the size of the resulting set. But, the notation *should* *directly* imply the operation we're performing, which is namely taking in two sets as input and outputting all the ways the elements in those sets can be mapped to each other."

Comment: I also think that the notation is not ideal; yes, it implicitly tells you something about the cardinality of the set, but so what? I would much rather like a notation like {A -> B} or even (A -> B) as it would make things such as function composition syntactically much clearer IMO. It would be closer to notations used in CS (e.g.,  type theory or functional programming languages).