# Problem with functor category notation

Tags: category-theory, notation, functors

I'm reading Mac Lane's category theory book. The notation $A^B$, $A$ and $B$ categories, is introduced for a category of functors $B\to A$ as objects and natural transformations of these functors as arrows. The author has used it in several different situations that I, with weak background in mathematics, don't understand clearly. I list a few of them below,

1. $C^X$ for $C$ category and $X$ set,
2. $\prod_j b=b^J$ for $b$ an object and $J$ an index category,
3. $c^{b\times b'}\cong (c^b)^{b'}$ for $c$, $b$ and $b'$ objects,
4. $G^X$ for $G$ group and $X$ category,
5. $X^T$ for $X$ category and $T$ functor,
6. $F^T$ for $F$ and $T$ both functors,
7. $\eta ^T$ for $\eta$ natural transformation and $T$ functor.

(1), (2) and (3) are OK since $X$ of (1), $b$ of (2), and $c$, $b$ and $b'$ of (3) are discrete categories. Now, let me list my questions as well.

- How is the interpretation of $b^J$ in (2) or the terms in (3) related to the simple notation $x^y$ in arithmetic? and more importantly,
- What's the meaning of the terms in (4) to (7)? More specifically, if they are representations of functor categories, what are their objects and arrows?

I know it's a long question. I already appreciate your answers.

Comment: Usually, [$A^B$  denotes the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204886/notation-for-expressing-sets-of-functions).

Comment: So in 1 we have all functors from set $X$ to category $C$ and in 4 we all functors from category $X$ to group $G$.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA but a functor is a morphism of categories. They map objects and arrows of one category to those of another. What are the arrows of $G$ in 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one fundamental example you should add to your list: functions from sets to sets.

The number of functions from a finite set $A$ to another finite set $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, where $|A|$ and $|B|$ are the number of elements in the sets. This is the origin of the notation $B^A$ for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$. Most of your examples expand the analogy to another situation.

- $C^X$ for $C$ category and $X$ set. Here $C^X$ is the set of functors from $X$ to $C$. Since $X$ is a set it can be treated as a category with its only morphisms the identities from each element to itself. Functors from such a discrete category reduce to functions from $X$ to the collection of objects of $C$.
- $c^{b\times b'} \cong (c^b)^{b'}$ for $c$, $b$ and $b'$ objects. Here, we're using the notation as an internalization of the set of morphisms from $b$ to $c$. Rather than a set, we can sometimes have objects in the same category that act like the hom sets.
- $G^X$ for $G$ group and $X$ category. This is similar to the first example. Here, $G$ is made into a category by giving it a single object and making the morphisms from that object to itself the elements of $G$. Composition is just the group operation.
- $F^T$ for $F$ and $T$ both functors. Here we're using the usual category structure on the collection of functors between two fixed categories. The objects are functors and the morphisms are natural transformations. So $F^T$ is the set of natural transformations from $F$ to $T$.

One other example doesn't *quite* fit into the same vein, but is still closely analogous.

- $\prod_j b=b^J$ for $b$ an object and $J$ an index category. At the very least, it should make sense that taking the product of a bunch of copies of an object is an exponential. In lots of concrete cases, it does still make sense to think of $b^J$ as the collection of functions from $J$ to $b$, but given the structure of an object of the category. For example, the set of functions from any set into a ring can be given a ring structure.

The last two examples, I'd need more context or I'm not familiar with the origin of the notation.

- $X^T$ for $X$ category and $T$ functor. I believe this is the category of $T$-algebras. A $T$-algebra $A$ has (as part or all of the data, depending on whether we're talking about algebras of a monad or algebras of a plain functor), a morphism $T(A) \to A$. So there's some notion that there are "morphisms from $T$ to (particular objects of) $X$", but I'm not sure that that's why this notation is used here.
- $\eta ^T$ for $\eta$ natural transformation and $T$ functor. I'm not familiar with this usage.

---

It may be worth noting that some of the notation in *Categories for the Working Mathematician* is outdated so you shouldn't use it as your sole source. Read other books and papers to see what notation other people use for these concepts.

Comment: Dear @S.C. thanks for the perfect answer. As for $X^T$ you're right, it's the category of T-algebras. But I can't still imagine a morphism "from a functor $T$" to an object.

Comment: $\eta ^T$ appears in a theorem stating that every monad is defined by its $T$-algebras. if $\langle T,\eta ,\mu \rangle$ is a monad in $X$, then the set of all $T$-algebras and their morphisms form a category $X^T$, and there would be an adjunction $\langle F^T,G^T;\eta ^T,\epsilon ^T\rangle :X\to X^T$ .... This may help.

Comment: I also appreciate if you have suggestions for changing the title, since the notation has a more general use than I thought.